# CyanogenMod on Android emulator - is it possible?

Tags: android, android-emulator, rom, cyanogenmod

I'm testing several modifications of Cyanogen MOD ROM's. It's not really comfortable to test them on real device. So the question: is it possible to install custom ROM (in particular CyanogenMod) on standard (or non-standard) Android emulator?

Comment: You might also get useful answers at http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Run the **Android SDK Manager** and in menus, navigate to **Tools->Manage Add-on Sites**. In the window that opens, click the **User Defined Sites** tab and click the **New** button.

Enter the following URL:

```
http://nushio.fedorapeople.org/cyanogenmod/repository.xml
```

After installing it and refreshing the packages list, you will find CyanogenMod-Kang Emulator in Android API 9, revision 3.

Install and enjoy!

Comment: btw, if I were to do run the build (cm for emulator), should I be using device "goldfish" in the command, e.g. lunch cm_goldfish_userdebug?

Comment: There was an interesting [edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4147604) that was rejected. Maybe you would like to apply it manually.

Answer (score 0):

For a way that still works with Cyanogen 13 see http://www.modaco.com/forums/topic/289928-testing-getting-an-emulator-up-and-running-a-full-rom-with-the-market-etc/
and http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=906161

In short:

- install ADT
- open SDK manager: tools/android
- install Android 6.0 (for CM-13)
- maybe install Tools/ Android SDK Tools & Platformtools latest version
- maybe install Extras/ GoogleRepo, AndroidSupportRepo & -Lib
- select Tools/Manage AVDs
- create new device, create new AVD
- place system.img into ~/.android/avd/

For a device that is officially supported by CM select from http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Devices

- Vendor: Google
- CM version you want

I wasn't yet able to make this really work... but it should.